# Change border color of material ui checkbox

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, material-ui, styling

Here is my checkbox when checked:

[image]

Here is my checkbox when not checked:

[image]

All of the posts relating to styling the checkbox pertain to the fill color, the check color, etc.  I must be missing something obvious here - just trying to make the border dark!

My code:

```
<Grid item xs={12}>
  <FormControlLabel control={<Checkbox onChange={(event) => {
    console.log(event.target.checked)
    setValue('isParty', false)
  }} />} label="Party" />
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

pink is the color of border

```
     <Checkbox 
                 sx={{
                      color: "pink",
                      '&.Mui-checked': {
                      color: "red",
                       },
                     }}
     />
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does it support css variables? I've tried `hsl(var(--twc-text-links-primary)` without luck, although `<div style={{ color: "hsl(var(--twc-text-links-primary)" }}>hello</div>` works.